# regular expression to validate the url

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Q: I want  a regular expression to validate the URL but i wanna to allow this character(~)the Tilda

something like this url:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/~/`
allowing `http` or without `http`

thanks in advance

**EDIT**:

i find a perfect one finally:
`(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?`
but i wanna to allow the user to enter the url with the protocol or without it to prevent any confusion how to do that.

Comment: no answer is correct i try this url `http://validator.w3.org/check` it is not valid i try to put ~ it doesn't work , i wanna a validator to assure that url is valid.

Comment: ((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?

Comment: thank u so much ,,please edit your answer with this one to consider it as an answer to the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow non-consecutive tildes:

```
\w+([-+.'~]\w+)*
```

To allow tildes anywhere:

```
[\w~]+([-+.'][\w~]+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this one:

```
\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

if you don't need the HTTP,FTP... youc an take it off like:

```
\b[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

Regards,
HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do u want. But

```
\w+([~'\.]\w+)+
```

Valid for

```
justname'com
just_name~com
justname.com
```

Invalid for

```
justname
just-name-com
```

If you use

```
\w+([~]?)\w+\.\w+
```

Valid for

```
justname.com
just~name.com
```

Invalid for

```
justname'com
just_name~com
just-name-com
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good regular expressions site [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) where you can get almost any regular expressions. Think this would be useful to you.