# Can any one help me out in creating a regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to validate these type of URls

```
http://anyword.anyword.anyword/anyword/anyword/download.aspx?anyword=http://www.anyword.anyword/anyword/anyword/anyword/ab-cd.cab
```

anyword could be anything(only strings though)
but i need to have `.cab` at the end

Ex:

```
http://stack.meta.com/default/cabs/newpage.aspx?mylink=http://www.stack.com/pages/sections/articles/en-ia.cab
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What are "only strings"?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: using `anyword` and then `download` as a distinctly different 'word' gives the impression that `download` must appear literally within a matched string - however your example does not represent this.

Comment: Okay my fault, even 'download' is not a distinct word..it could be any valid string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

For .cab at last

```
^(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(cab)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$
```

For all

```
^(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http://[\s\S]{1,200}(?=.cab)
```

If you're using a single link (not searching from many links) then this might suffice.
You can easily modify and test this regex @ http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

I'm still a beginner @ regex construction so forgive me if it doesn't work the way you need.

Comment: Use lookbehind or it won't work; also escape the dot: `(?<=\.cab)`. And why the limitation to 200 characters? Also, why do you allow spaces?

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://www.regexlib.com site for making your regular expression validation.....

this is the best site where all best validation expressions available and lots of

Answer (score 1):

To match that it is ending with `.cab` you can use:

```
\.cab$
```

notice the `$` that is the important point defining the end of your string.

The other part depends on how deep you want to validate your link. A simple check would be

```
^http.*\.cab$
```

that would allow everything that starts with `http` and ends with `.cab`

For more sophisticated URL checks you can search here on SO. see e.g. this [questions/4538212/regular-expression-to-validate-the-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538212/regular-expression-to-validate-the-url). This has been discussed here many times.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^http:\/\/((\w+\.?)+\/?){1,4}\.aspx\?\w+\=http:\/\/((\w+\.?)+\/){1,4}[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}\.cab$
```

Though I believe your question lacks requirements... :)

Answer (score 0):

IMP, this maybe match it. `"\\.cab"` It needs 2 "\". Hope help you!

Comment: This will match `.cab` anywhere in the string